# "undefined reference to `tclStubsPtr'" error returned ad nauseam when compiling TCL makefile in GCC

Tags: c, makefile, tcl, git-bash, tk-toolkit

Entered `$ make -f /c/Users/billa/Documents/htmlwidget/mingw.mk` into Git BASH MINGW64 when trying to compile a TCL package and the console returned this error:

```
C:/ActiveTcl/lib/tclstub86.lib C:/ActiveTcl/lib/tkstub86.lib -LC:/Tcl/lib

Building Tkhtml 3

COMPILE = mingw32-gcc -O2 -DNDEBUG  -DUSE_TCL_STUBS=1 -DUSE_TK_STUBS=1 -IC:/ActiveTcl/include -I. -IC:/Users/billa/Documents/htmlwidget/src/ -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DUSE_TK_STUBS
TCLSH   = tclsh

$(BCC) C:/Users/billa/Documents/htmlwidget/tools/lemon.c -o lemon
cp C:/Users/billa/Documents/htmlwidget/src/cssparse.lem .
cp C:/Users/billa/Documents/htmlwidget/tools/lempar.c .
$(LEMON) cssparse.lem
$(COMPILE) -c cssparse.c -o cssparse.o
mingw32-gcc -shared  htmlparse.o htmldraw.o htmltcl.o htmlimage.o htmltree.o htmltagdb.o cssparse.o css.o cssprop.o csssearch.o htmlstyle.o htmllayout.o htmlprop.o htmlfloat.o htmlhash.o swproc.o htmlinline.o htmltable.o restrack.o cssdynamic.o htmldecode.o htmltext.o htmlutil.o "C:/ActiveTcl/lib/tclstub86.lib"  "C:/ActiveTcl/lib/tkstub86.lib"  -LC:/Tcl/lib -o libTkhtml3.dll
htmlparse.o:htmlparse.c:(.text+0x379): undefined reference to `tclStubsPtr'
htmlparse.o:htmlparse.c:(.text+0xf0a): undefined reference to `tclStubsPtr'
htmlparse.o:htmlparse.c:(.text+0x101b): undefined reference to `tclStubsPtr'
htmlparse.o:htmlparse.c:(.text+0x107b): undefined reference to `tclStubsPtr'
htmlparse.o:htmlparse.c:(.text+0x10b0): undefined reference to `tclStubsPtr'
htmlparse.o:htmlparse.c:(.text+0x10bf): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x14b3): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x3a2e): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x48a7): undefined reference to `tkIntXlibStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x4a7a): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x4ca8): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x54cb): undefined reference to `tkIntXlibStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x5627): more undefined references to `tkStubsPtr' follow
htmltcl.o:htmltcl.c:(.text+0x11b): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmltcl.o:htmltcl.c:(.text+0x4c5): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmltcl.o:htmltcl.c:(.text+0x586): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmltcl.o:htmltcl.c:(.text+0x9f4): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmltcl.o:htmltcl.c:(.text+0xfba): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmltcl.o:htmltcl.c:(.text+0x295c): more undefined references to `tkStubsPtr' follow
htmltcl.o:htmltcl.c:(.text+0x2c33): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmltcl.o:htmltcl.c:(.text+0x2d97): more undefined references to `tkStubsPtr' follow
htmltcl.o:htmltcl.c:(.text+0x2e4f): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmltcl.o:htmltcl.c:(.text+0x3317): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmltcl.o:htmltcl.c:(.text+0x3539): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmlimage.o:htmlimage.c:(.text+0xb09): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmltree.o:htmltree.c:(.text+0x2b2): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmltree.o:htmltree.c:(.text+0x874): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmltree.o:htmltree.c:(.text+0x228c): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmltree.o:htmltree.c:(.text+0x3508): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmltree.o:htmltree.c:(.text+0x3e01): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmlstyle.o:htmlstyle.c:(.text+0x723): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmllayout.o:htmllayout.c:(.text+0x1625): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmllayout.o:htmllayout.c:(.text+0x3906): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmlprop.o:htmlprop.c:(.text+0xa77): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmlprop.o:htmlprop.c:(.text+0x1379): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmlprop.o:htmlprop.c:(.text+0x197b): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmlprop.o:htmlprop.c:(.text+0x3086): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmlprop.o:htmlprop.c:(.text+0x341b): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmltable.o:htmltable.c:(.text+0x3d4): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmltext.o:htmltext.c:(.text+0xf40): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmltext.o:htmltext.c:(.text+0x12d7): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmltext.o:htmltext.c:(.text+0x1404): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [C:/Users/billa/Documents/htmlwidget/main.mk:56: libTkhtml3.dll] Error 1
```

The Configuration for mingw.mk is shown here

```
# CC                  Command to invoke C compiler.
# CFLAGS              Flags to pass to C compiler.
# SHARED_LIB          Name of shared-library to build.
# MKSHLIB             Command to build shared library.
# TCLSH               Command to execute a Tcl shell.
# TCLLIB              Options to pass to CC to link with Tcl.
# TOP                 Top of source tree (directory with this file).

##### Top of the Tkhtml source tree - the directory with this file in it.
#
TOP = C:/Users/billa/Documents/htmlwidget

##### BUILD can be DEBUG or RELEASE.
#
# BUILD = DEBUG
BUILD = RELEASE

HV3_POLIPO = /home/dan/work/polipo/hv3_polipo.exe

##### Version of and path to the Tcl installation to use.
#
TCLVERSION = 86
TCL = C:/ActiveTcl

##### Flags passed to the C-compiler to link to Tcl.
#
# TCLLIB = -L$(TCL)/lib -ltclstub$(TCLVERSION) -ltkstub$(TCLVERSION)
TCLLIB = -L$(TCL)/lib -ltcl$(TCLVERSION) -ltk$(TCLVERSION) -ltclstub$(TCLVERSION) -    ltkstub$(TCLVERSION)

##### Extra libraries used by Tcl on Linux. These flags are only required to
#     staticly link Tcl into an executable
#
# TCLLIB_DEBUG += -L/usr/X11R6/lib/ -lX11 -ldl -lm

BCC = gcc
CC = mingw32-gcc

CFLAGS_RELEASE = -O2 -DNDEBUG 
CFLAGS_DEBUG   = -g
CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS_$(BUILD))
CFLAGS += -DUSE_TCL_STUBS=1 -DUSE_TK_STUBS=1

##### The name of the shared library file to build.
#
SHARED_LIB_DEBUG = libTkhtml3g.dll
SHARED_LIB_RELEASE = libTkhtml3.dll
SHARED_LIB = $(SHARED_LIB_$(BUILD))

##### Command to build a shared library from a set of object files. The
#     command executed will be:
# 
#         $(MKSHLIB) $(OBJS) $(TCLSTUBSLIB) -o $(SHARED_LIB)
#
MKSHLIB = $(CC) -shared 
TCLSTUBSLIB =  "$(TCL)/lib/tclstub86.lib" 
TCLSTUBSLIB += "$(TCL)/lib/tkstub86.lib" 
TCLSTUBSLIB += -LC:/Tcl/lib

##### Commands to run tclsh on the build platform (to generate C files
#     to be passed to $(CC) from tcl scripts).
#
TCLSH = tclsh

##### Strip the shared library
#
STRIP = mingw32-strip

MKSTARKIT = tclkit /home/dan/bin/sdx.kit wrap
STARKITRT = /home/dan/work/tclkit-win32.upx.exe

##### Javascript libaries - libgc.a and libsee.a
#
JS_SHARED_LIB = libTclsee.dll

JSLIB   = $(HOME)/javascript/mingw/install/lib/libsee.a
JSLIB  += $(HOME)/javascript/mingw/install/lib/libgc.a
JSFLAGS = -I$(HOME)/javascript/mingw/install/include

#
# End of configuration section.
###########################################################################

default: binaries

hv3-win32.exe: hv3_img.kit
    cp $(STARKITRT) starkit_runtime
    $(MKSTARKIT) hv3_img.bin -runtime ./starkit_runtime
    mv hv3_img.bin hv3-win32.exe
    chmod 644 hv3-win32.exe

###############################################################################
include $(TOP)/main.mk
```

It may be important to note that I am largely unfamiliar with this software.

Further code and documentation can be found here:
https://github.com/olebole/tkhtml3/blob/master/COMPILE.txt
https://github.com/olebole/tkhtml3/blob/master/main.mk

Edited for readability.

Comment: Your question misses a few important details and context: Do you have an ActiveTcl installation? At `C:/ActiveTcl/*`?

Comment: There are folders C:/ActiveTcl/* it if that's what you mean, and the folder C:/ActiveTcl/bin has Applications 'tclsht', 'tclsh86t', 'tclsht' and 'wish', 'wish86t', 'wisht'.

Comment: Does that directory listing include any static libraries with "stub" in the name? Because that's what you need to link against. (It handles the binding to the implementation in a smarter way than is normal on Windows.)

Comment: There are files with "stub" / "stubs" in the name but there ether .c files or .lib files, all seem to be in the */lib directory.

Comment: `.lib` is the extension for a static library on Windows. The one with a name like `tclstub.lib` (maybe with a version number in) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Found "C:\ActiveTcl\lib\tclstub86.lib" & "C:\ActiveTcl\lib\tkstub86.lib"